# How to change the temp upload path runtime?

Tags: php

I would like to change my applications temp path to a subfolder, so that users on a shared server cannot see any uploaded files.

I would like to be able to do this run-time, or via .htaccess if possible (although I would like the new temp path to be a subdir of the original temp path). I can't edit the php.ini on the shared server.

I know I can check what the tmp path is via sys_get_temp_dir(), but there doesn't seem to be a way to set it.

Is this even possible?

Comment: If other users have access to the main temp path, surely they have access to subfolders of it? Or are you going to explicitly restrict permissions on your app-specific temp path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','your/path/here/');
```

> The temporary directory used for
>   storing files when doing file upload.
>   Must be writable by whatever user PHP
>   is running as. If not specified PHP
>   will use the system's default.
>
> If the directory specified here is not
>   writable, PHP falls back to the system
>   default temporary directory. If
>   open_basedir is on, then the system
>   default directory must be allowed for
>   an upload to succeed.

[upload_tmp_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)

Answer (score 7):

maybe in '11, now not anymore.

As documented here [ini.list](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) 
and with reference to [modes](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php), 
'upload_tmp_dir' cannot be changed at run time.

thanks.